# Error launching Watchkit extension

Tags: xcode, ios8.4, watchapp

When I am trying to run the iwatch app getting [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your WatchKit Extension Bundle Identifier. You can also refer to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260222/how-can-i-avoid-the-error-error-launching-appname-watchkit-extension-when-tr)